# Scraping pdf files from web

Tags: r, pdf, web-scraping, download

This question was answered here ([Web scraping pdf files from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523977/web-scraping-pdf-files-from-html)) but the solution doesn't work for me on either my target url or the target url of the op. I'm not supposed to ask this question as an answer to the earlier post so I'm starting a new Q.

My code is exactly as per the op and the error message that I receive is 
"Error in download.file(links[i], destfile = save_names[i]) : 
  invalid 'url' argument"

The code I'm using is:

```
install.packages("RCurl")
install.packages("XML")
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url <- "https://www.bot.or.th/English/MonetaryPolicy/Northern/EconomicReport/Pages/Releass_Economic_north.aspx"
page   <- getURL(url)
parsed <- htmlParse(page)
links  <- xpathSApply(parsed, path="//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")
inds   <- grep("*.pdf", links)
links  <- links[inds]


regex_match <- regexpr("[^/]+$", links)
save_names <- regmatches(links, regex_match)

for(i in seq_along(links)){
  download.file(links[i], destfile=save_names[i])
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, 1, 5))

}
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Would be cool put in the begin of the script the packages...so you turn this a reproducible example.

Comment: Done as suggested @igorkf

Comment: Solved! I don't know *why* this works but it does. I have swapped the for loop for the following code and it works: Map (function(u, d) download.file(u, d, mode='wb'), links, save_names)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I don't know why this works but it does. I have swapped the for loop for the following code and it works:

```
Map (function(u, d) download.file(u, d, mode='wb'), links, save_names)
```